# async and nodes js function console.log recieves NaN, NaN, Nan need help outputting the the string out as a string and not a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nan

full code and the error I m getting below I would really like to get the output working correctly so I can move on in my code

```
var app = require('express')()
          , server = require('http').createServer(app)
          , fs = require('fs')
          , exec = require('child_process').exec
          , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var async = require('async');

server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
    // console.log(async);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //socket.emit('dinpu', { hello: 'world' });
    // myModule('fam@btin.com:asdfef');
    socket.on('dout', function (data) {
    //module2(data);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data.message));
    for(i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
        //data.message[i] = data.message[i].replace(/"/g, "");  
    }
    module1(data.message);
    module2(data.message);

    function module1(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }


    function async(arg, callback) {
        console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
        setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);
    }

    function module2(data) {
        function final() { console.log('Done', results); }
        var items = data;
        var results = [];
        function series(item) {
            if(item) {
                async( item, function(result) {
                    results.push(result);
                    return series(items.shift());
                });
            } else {
                return final();
            }
        }
        series(items.shift());
    }


});
});
```

everything works fine except for this part

```
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }
```

I get the results

```
do something with 'dfhfgh', return 1 sec later
do something with 'gfhjghj', return 1 sec later
do something with 'gfhjghj', return 1 sec later
do something with 'fghjgh', return 1 sec later
do something with 'ghjfhj', return 1 sec later
Done [ NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ]<<< this is the error I need it to output the strings
```

any help fixing my code I would really appreciate it :).

I have fixed this myself now after not many helpful comments after a closer look I managed to get this working

so after correcting my node server I now get the proper results heres the correct code and results below

```
  var app = require('express')()
 , server = require('http').createServer(app)
 , fs = require('fs')
 , exec = require('child_process').exec
 , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var async = require('async');
server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
// console.log(async);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //socket.emit('dinpu', { hello: 'world' });
 // myModule('fam@btin.com:asdfef');
 socket.on('dout', function (data) {
 //module2(data);
 //console.log(JSON.parse(data.message));
 for(i = 0; i < data.message.length; i++) {
 //data.message[i] = data.message[i].replace(/"/g, ""); 

 }
 module1(data.message);
 module2(data.message);

 function module1(data) {
     console.log(data);
 }


function async(arg, callback) {
  console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\' return 1 sec later');
  setTimeout(function() { callback('\''+arg+'\''); }, 1000);
}

    function module2(data) {
    function final() { console.log('Done', '\''+results+'\''); }
    var items = data;
    var results = [];
    function series(item) {
                        if(item) {
        async( item, function(result) {
                results.push(result);
                return series(items.shift());
            });
         } else {
           return final();
      }
    }
    series(items.shift());
}


});
});
```

results

```
do something with 'sdfg' return 1 sec later
do something with 'srg' return 1 sec later
do something with 'sdf' return 1 sec later
Done ''sdfg','srg','sdf''
```

Comment: what exactly do you expect it to output?

Comment: [ dfhfgh, gfhjghj, gfhjghj, fghjgh, ghjfhj ]

Comment: then try to remove the `* 2` part ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix this just results in exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);`

this line, `arg` is not a number, you can not use `* 2`

Comment: what can I use instead of the number then ? I understand what you mean I just don't think this is much of an answer an example on how I would fix this would be great

Comment: @user3385289 Its not really possible to know how to fix it.  What do you expect multiplying a string by `2` to do?

Comment: I am asking on how to fix this I don't need to multiply the argument its an obious error all I want to do is output [ dfhfgh, gfhjghj, gfhjghj, fghjgh, ghjfhj ] I don't need anything else I have used an example to help me build this code so I am asking the correct way to modify it so I just outputs the strings